# How to make my app suitable for all iPhone sizes without using Auto-Layout?

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout, image-resizing

I was using auto-layout and since I was having too much trouble using it I have disabled it. What do I need to make an app that is suitable for all iPhone sizes?

Comment: You should really learn how to use auto layout. You can probably technically size things according to screen height and width but the burden will far exceed the amount of time it takes to learn auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add missing constraints at Resolve auto-layout issues. Before that you should adjust the wAny and hAny to base values to for all layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you must use autolayout - unless you want to write your own layout engine or resort to changing your code every time a new phone screen size comes out.